# Позиционирование кнопок управления слайдером слева и справа от пагинации

Tags: css, owl-carousel

Как расположить стрелки управления слайдером слева и справа от пагинации?

Не пойму, как лучше сделать позиционирование кнопок навигации.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Ну как-то так:

```css
body {
  background-color: dimgray;
}

.control {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 120px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.control span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.control .active {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.control .active:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #fff;
  cursor: default;
}

.control .left {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -30px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-width: 0 0 2px 2px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  line-height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.control .right {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: -30px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-width: 0 0 2px 2px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  line-height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}

.control span:hover,
.control .left:hover,
.control .right:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-color: #000;
}

.control .left:hover {
  left: -33px;
}

.control .right:hover {
  right: -33px;
}

.control .left,
.control .right {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="control">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <span class="active"></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Обычно делаю такую вёрстку:

```css
.slider-button {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.slider-button .button {
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: url('https://i.imgur.com/8pqCQ7Z.png') no-repeat center center / 100% auto;
  opacity: .65;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider-button .button.-prev {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.slider-button .button:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider-button .dots {
  max-width: 100%;
  cursor: default;
}

.slider-button .dot {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 100%;
  opacity: .65;
}

.slider-button .dot:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.slider-button .dot:not(.--active):hover {
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider-button .dot.--active {
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-button">
  <div class="button -prev"></div>
  <div class="dots">
    <div class="dot --active"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="button -next"></div>
</div>
```